# Oracle APEX: How to implement autocomplete Address

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I'm using APEX 4.2

I aim to make the address filling **autocomplet**: whene the end user starts filling the address, a lot of suggestions coming from a source (eg: table of all addresses) are appearing so the user can choose one of them.

I m looking how to do that on APEX 4.2

I m open to all suggestions

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried to use the Text Field with Autocomplete Page Item?

Comment: Yes, but the problem s where can I get information that will appear in the autocomplete ?

Comment: Is there a possibility to integrate the google map API into APEX and then have something to do the autocomplete from the data received from API ?

Comment: Yes you can [integrate google maps API with Apex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/integrating-apex-with-google-maps-169532.pdf) but is that what you really need? Will you have worldwide addresses? if just for a specific country i'm sure you can find a DB with the country streets and cities.

Comment: Thanks Cristian. Yes it s for a specific country. I have the DB of all addresses